# MySQL multiple calculations from one table using different where clauses

Tags: mysql, aggregate

I am new to MySQL and am trying to aggregate some statistics for a football game (American). I have one table "plays" which contains one row for each play in the game. I have figured out how to aggregate over 30 statistics that I want, but one's with multiple conditions have me stumped.

What I want is to have all my aggregation put into one table.

Here is my code (but I've only left in one line where I am calculating a statistic (in this case yards gained).

```
SELECT possession_team AS Team, ball_carrier_receiver AS Player,
sum(gain) AS YDS,
FROM plays WHERE run_pass='P' AND pass_result <>'S' AND pass_result <>'R'
GROUP BY possession_team, ball_carrier_receiver;
```

Here is my example of a calculation I am stuck on. I want to calculate yards after catch where pass_result='C', and I can do this with the following:

```
sum(gain) - sum(bia) AS 'TOT YAC',
```

But there is a condition I also need to meet on certain plays. If there is a Touchdown scored (series_end='Touchdown') then I need to subtract the extra yardage as there would be no yards after catch if ball is caught in the endzone. Player 1 catches an 18 yard Touchdown, but the BIA on that play was 21 (he caught it 3 yards into the endzone).

But I still need to calculate as sum(gain) - sum(bia) for all other plays where there is no touchdown.

Sample data:

| possession_team | run_pass | pass_result | ball_carrier_receiver | gain | bia | series_end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TA | P | C | 1 | 12 | 8 | NULL |
| TA | R | NULL | 29 | 3 | NULL | NULL |
| TA | P | C | 1 | 14 | 10 | NULL |
| TA | P | I | 1 | 0 | 18 | NULL |
| TA | P | S | 7 | -6 | NULL | Fumble |
| TA | P | C | 1 | 18 | 21 | Touchdown |

The correct answers for what player 1 should have for his Total gain is 44 (12+14+18), his Total BIA is 57 (8+10+18+21), and his Total YAC is 36 (8+10+21-(18-21)).

Comment: that is unreadable tryt to write a https://dbfiddle.uk with your data and the result should also be in table form

Comment: Thanks Barmar , I just tried to edit my table but you beat me to it.

Comment: Maybe `SUM(IF(pass_result = 'C', gain - bia, 0))`?

Comment: That won't account for the difference on plays where there is a touchdown. On those plays I need to subtract any additional yardage if bia is greater than gain.